# check if a part of an array element contains certain string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming an array containing student's names and their respective score, I want to retrieve the score of certain student (by checking if the array element contains the student's name (string))

I came up with this but it doesn't work

```js
var students = [
  ['David', 80],
  ['Dane', 77],
  ['Dick', 88],
  ['Donald', 95],
  ['Dean', 68]
];


function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    var name = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
    var string = students[i].toString();
    if (string.includes(name);) {
      alert(students[i][1]);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" /><button type="button" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: your array structure should contain data  `property_name:property_value` format,then you can use `indexOf` on property_name.

Comment: thanks a billion anyhow!

Comment: what do you want with more than one result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, except for the syntax error in the `if` condition, which has a `;` that should not be there. Remove it and it works:

```js
var students = [
    ['David', 80],
    ['Dane', 77],
    ['Dick', 88],
    ['Donald', 95],
    ['Dean', 68]
];

function test(){
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        var name = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
        var string = students[i].toString();
        if (string.includes(name))
        {
          console.log(students[i][1]);
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" /><button type="button" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

But there are some inefficiencies in your code:

- Don't read out the input value in every iteration of the loop, you just need to do this once.
- Instead of converting the pair `students[i]` to string, it seems more to the point to just look at `students[i][0]`, which is a string already
- Since you are using `.includes()` and thus are running on a modern browser, why not use the other features available in ES6, like `.find()`?

Here is the same with more efficient ES6 code:

```js
const students = [
    ['David', 80],
    ['Dane', 77],
    ['Dick', 88],
    ['Donald', 95],
    ['Dean', 68]
];

const box = document.getElementById("namebox");

function test(){
    const value = box.value;
    const match = students.find(student => student[0].includes(value));
    if (match) {
      console.log(match[1]);
    }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" /><button type="button" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: @mplungjan, OK so now my answer makes no sense anymore? I am not sure you should answer questions by fixing them ;-)

Comment: I put the typo back ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are doing `students[i].toString()`. This will return only a string which contains the items of the array. So suggest you don't do the `toString` and iterate over each item and use indexing. And also inside the first array you can contain `objects` of `students`, it will be more logically.

Move the

```
var namebox = document.getElementById("namebox");
```

out of the `for loop`. Every time engine spend a time to find the element in the for loop. So you get it once and use many times.

**ES6 syntax**

```js
let students = [
    {name: 'David', score: 80},
    {name: 'Dane', score: 77},
    {name: 'Dick', score: 88},
    {name: 'Donald', score: 95},
    {name: 'Dean', score: 68}
];

let namebox = document.getElementById("namebox");

function test(){
  
   let name = namebox.value;

   students.forEach(item => {

     if(item.name.includes(name)){
       console.log(name, item.name, item.score);
     }

  });
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" />
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

**ES5 syntax**

```js
var students = [
        {name: 'David', score: 80},
        {name: 'Dane', score: 77},
        {name: 'Dick', score: 88},
        {name: 'Donald', score: 95},
        {name: 'Dean', score: 68}
    ];

var namebox = document.getElementById("namebox");

function test(){
  
   var name = namebox.value;

   for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){

      if(students[i].name.indexOf(name) !== -1)  {
         console.log(name,students[i].name,students[i].score);
      }

   }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" />
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return an array with the matched names.

```js
function getStudentsByName() {
    var name = document.getElementById("namebox").value.toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(students.filter(function (a) {
        return a[0].toLowerCase() === name;
    }), 0, 4);
}

var students = [['David', 67], ['David', 80], ['Dane', 77], ['Dick', 88], ['Donald', 95], ['Dean', 68]];
```

```html
<input type="text" id="namebox" /><button type="button" onclick="getStudentsByName()">Click</button>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```